# Importing all mysql database at once

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, mysql

mysql allows you to export complete database at once but I found if really very tough to import the complete database at once.

I used `mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > alldb.sql` and when I am trying to import the complete database by `mysql -u root -p < alldb.sql` command its giving me very weird error.

```
Error
SQL query:

--
-- Database: `fadudeal_blog`
--
-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table `wp_commentmeta`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `wp_commentmeta` (

 `meta_id` BIGINT( 20 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `comment_id` BIGINT( 20 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
 `meta_key` VARCHAR( 255 ) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL ,
 `meta_value` LONGTEXT COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
PRIMARY KEY (  `meta_id` ) ,
KEY  `comment_id` (  `comment_id` ) ,
KEY  `meta_key` (  `meta_key` ( 191 ) )
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT =1;

MySQL said: Documentation

#1046 - No database selected
```

Its saying **#1046 - No database selected** , my question is when the mysql knows that I have exported the complete database at once then how can I specify just one database name?

I don't now if I am right or wrong but I tried it multiple times, I found the same problem. Please let me know how we can upload or import complete database at once.

Comment: Looks like the exported file do not contains the create database Statement.

Comment: Hi Jens, any idea how to fix it?

Comment: `mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases` do it for me

Comment: worked for me thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rohit , i think you will have to create the database and then issue a USE  and then run the SQL. I looked at the manual here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-batch-commands.html and it also provides an option for you to mention the db_name when you connect itself 
something like mysql  -u root -p < sql.sql (assuming the db is already created. It may be worth a try doing that way

> shell> mysqldump --databases db1 db2 db3 > dump.sql
>   The --databases option causes all names on the command line to be treated as database names. Without this option, mysqldump treats the first name as a database name and those following as table names.

With --all-databases or --databases, mysqldump writes CREATE DATABASE and USE statements prior to the dump output for each database. This ensures that when the dump file is reloaded, it creates each database if it does not exist and makes it the default database so database contents are loaded into the same database from which they came. If you want to cause the dump file to force a drop of each database before recreating it, use the --add-drop-database option as well. In this case, mysqldump writes a DROP DATABASE statement preceding each CREATE DATABASE statement.

from : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html

Comment: Yes I did, Its importing only one database at once ie. 1st database out of 13 database. How can I upload all the 13 Database at once?

Comment: I just added some more information from the MYSQL documentation. This is on version 5.7.4 , which version of MySQL do you use...

Comment: There was create database command and use database command missing the sql file, so I added and it worked for me.